# apps automatically open in my cell phone screen how

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

In my cell phone Micromax canvas L A 108, Apps automaticall open and in my messaging screen "i" text automatically typing continously. is it a software problem or display problem. please give the answer

Comment: I had this issue on my Micromax Funbook. It was replaced under warranty.

Comment: Thank you Rohith. Whether entire phone replced or display changed? My phone also under warrenty.

Comment: I got a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the phone and see whether the problem goes off. If you have the opportunity, enable "Show touches" under developer options. This will show where exactly the phone is simulating the touches and with that you can see whether it is a hardware issue. If you do not see the touches highlighted, but the apps automatically open then it is most likely a software issue. In that case, restart the app in recovery mode and do a factory rest. Also, you can try installing some other compatible ROM.

If you see the touch spots, then it is most likely to be a faulty digitizer. In that case you can either claim warranty or get it replaced.

You can see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljU0ktBvi_Q) video which demonstrates how to enable "Show touches" option.